# Team Foundation Server - Use API to Sync to SVN

Tags: svn, tfs, version-control, synchronization

Has anyone out there used TFS's API to synchronize different types of repositories?  I have a SVN repo that I want to sync with a TFS repo.  More accurately, I just want to take everything latest from SVN occasionally (nightly) and dump it out to TFS as the latest version.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The people who run CodePlex created a bridge between TFS and SVN. It's called SvnBridge. They have 2 versions of the app. One version runs in IIS, and the other version is a client.

You might be able to talk to the project and see if you can do what you want. I believe that the actual flow right now is SVN to TFS, but I don't see it couldn't go the other way.

http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge